# Image not uploading in laravel media library

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I just started with laravel media library. While uploading images to the database I am getting an error. I tried searching in documentation But I am not finding an answer for this.

the error which I am getting

```
Argument 1 passed to Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\FileAdder::processMediaItem() must be an 
instance of Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia, instance of App\Service given, called in 
C:\xampp\htdocs\Matheen\furniture_backend\vendor\spatie\
laravel-medialibrary\src\MediaCollections\FileAdder.php on line 372
```

controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $service = Service::create([
            'service_name' => $request->service_name
        ]);

        $file = $request->file('image');
        $service->addMedia($file)->toMediaCollection('services');

        return redirect('services')->with('success','Service Added Successfully');

    }
```

Model

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\MediaCollections\Models\Media;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\InteractsWithMedia;
use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;


class Service extends Model
{
    use InteractsWithMedia;

     protected $fillable = ['service_name'];


    public function registerMediaCollections(): void
    {
        $this->addMediaCollection('services');
    }

     public function registerMediaConversions(Media $media = null): void
     {
        $this->addMediaConversion('thumbnail')
            ->width(1000)
            ->height(250);
     }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in model class statement
you have: "class Service extends Model"
you need: "class Service extends Model implements HasMedia"

```php
...
...

use Spatie\MediaLibrary\HasMedia;

class Service extends Model implements HasMedia 
{
   // code
}
..
```

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow..  Please review the how to ask question to ask a proper question.. You have to show the code which is generating the error or exactly tell us what error are you facing? what have you tried to solve it... for more visit the link... https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: you are right my model was not extending HasMedia Trait. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

i did this

```
composer require spatie/laravel-medialibrary:10.0.7
```

and problem solved
laravel 9
medialibrary 10.0.7

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).